# OpenWrt: Can' connect to wifi

Tags: wifi, openwrt, access-point

I have an ASUS RT-N56U router with OpenWrt 21.02.3 installed (fresh install).

I ultimately want to set it up as wifi repeater, but I'm already struggling with setting it up as simple wifi access point (so this is what the question will be about).
I looked at a bunch of tutorials, but every tutorial leaves me with the same outcome.

#### Situation

I can find my access point from other devices, but I can't connect. 
When I choose the AP to connect, **the connection is constantly pending.**

#### Question

How do I set my OpenWrt router up as access point?

#### edit: Answering process

- It seems like this is a DHCP problem.

  - Option 1: open open Interface -> [your interface] -> edit -> DHCP Server -> Set up DHCP server -> uncheck *Ignore this interface*
  - Option 2: Open `Wireless` -> [your SSID] -> General Setup -> Network -> choose `lan` (apparently the only option, that provides a working DHCP setup)

#### What I did / tried

##### General setup

- Network -> Wireless -> radio0 (2.5 Ghz) -> add
- Settings:

  - Mostly default
  - Interface Configuration -> General Setup -> Network: `wwan` (is a `Client` of a wifi network using the 5 Ghz interface)
  - Advanced settings: Country Code: Chose my country.
- Result: [image]

##### Static DHCP lease

I thought this might be a *not working DHCP problem*, so I set up static leases like below. However, I still can't connect.

[image]

##### Static IP address on client

Won't work either. tried it with several different devices.

##### Syslog output

```
Sun May  1 23:24:15 2022 daemon.warn dnsmasq-dhcp[21906]: DHCP packet received on wlan0 which has no address
Sun May  1 23:24:24 2022 daemon.warn dnsmasq-dhcp[21906]: DHCP packet received on wlan0 which has no address
Sun May  1 23:24:32 2022 daemon.warn dnsmasq-dhcp[21906]: DHCP packet received on wlan0 which has no address
Sun May  1 23:24:41 2022 daemon.warn dnsmasq-dhcp[21906]: DHCP packet received on wlan0 which has no address
Sun May  1 23:24:49 2022 daemon.notice hostapd: wlan0: AP-STA-DISCONNECTED 84:8e:0c:c2:45:00
Sun May  1 23:24:49 2022 daemon.info hostapd: wlan0: STA 84:8e:0c:c2:45:00 IEEE 802.11: disassociated
Sun May  1 23:24:50 2022 daemon.info hostapd: wlan0: STA 84:8e:0c:c2:45:00 IEEE 802.11: authenticated
Sun May  1 23:24:50 2022 daemon.info hostapd: wlan0: STA 84:8e:0c:c2:45:00 IEEE 802.11: associated (aid 1)
Sun May  1 23:24:50 2022 daemon.notice hostapd: wlan0: AP-STA-CONNECTED 84:8e:0c:c2:45:00
Sun May  1 23:24:50 2022 daemon.warn dnsmasq-dhcp[21906]: DHCP packet received on wlan0 which has no address
Sun May  1 23:24:51 2022 daemon.warn dnsmasq-dhcp[21906]: DHCP packet received on wlan0 which has no address
Sun May  1 23:24:53 2022 daemon.notice hostapd: wlan0: AP-STA-DISCONNECTED 84:8e:0c:c2:45:00
Sun May  1 23:24:53 2022 daemon.info hostapd: wlan0: STA 84:8e:0c:c2:45:00 IEEE 802.11: disassociated
Sun May  1 23:24:55 2022 daemon.info hostapd: wlan0: STA 84:8e:0c:c2:45:00 IEEE 802.11: deauthenticated due to inactivity (timer DEAUTH/REMOVE)
Sun May  1 23:24:56 2022 daemon.info hostapd: wlan0: STA 84:8e:0c:c2:45:00 IEEE 802.11: authenticated
Sun May  1 23:24:56 2022 daemon.info hostapd: wlan0: STA 84:8e:0c:c2:45:00 IEEE 802.11: associated (aid 1)
Sun May  1 23:24:56 2022 daemon.notice hostapd: wlan0: AP-STA-CONNECTED 84:8e:0c:c2:45:00
Sun May  1 23:24:57 2022 daemon.warn dnsmasq-dhcp[21906]: DHCP packet received on wlan0 which has no address
Sun May  1 23:24:58 2022 daemon.warn dnsmasq-dhcp[21906]: DHCP packet received on wlan0 which has no address
Sun May  1 23:25:01 2022 daemon.warn dnsmasq-dhcp[21906]: DHCP packet received on wlan0 which has no address
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ultimately ended up

- not figuring out the problem
- Resetting the router
- Doing [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/701347/336392)