# OpenWrt: How to use wifi as WAN connection?

Tags: openwrt

#### Situation:

My internet provide only provides wifi / WLAN in my home. I don't have a wired connection to the outside world.

#### Goal

I'd like to create a LAN in my home that uses the provided wifi connection as WAN port.

#### Question

How do I configure my OpenWrt router to do that?

#### Previous research

I've read many questions here on SE and on the internet talking about *bridging* and how to do it. I ended up with 16 lost hours and no showable result.

Comment: I was looking for how to use an OpenWRT router as a travel router, connecting to hotel/coffeeshop hotspots and attaching devices as a personal LAN. This question is actually the same thing, except at home.

Answer (score 7):

I advice you to start from a freshly resetted / installed system.

### Introduction

- Open your Web UI (192.168.1.1)
- Go to `Network` -> `Wireless`
- It should look something like this: [image: screenshot of Wireless interfaces]

  - Notice:

    - "radio0" and "radio1" can be interpreted as "wifi device 0" and "wifi device 1"
    - The Radios might show a message "inactive". Don't bother about that
    - A "radio" is nothing you can connect to from your computer. Your computer will connect to a *Network*.
    - There are already two networks set up - one for each radio. One with SSID `OpenWrt2` and one with SSID `OpenWrt5`.
    - Both of them are *disabled*. You can test your wifi connections by `Enable` button and connect to it for another device.

### Setup

For the following I presume that

- Your WAN wifi uses 2.4 GHz
- Your LAN wifi uses 5 GHz
- Your Wired LAN and wifi LAN will be on the same network.

Steps:

1. Many tutorials tell you to change the static LAN IP address of your router. *Don't*. It won't work anyway.
2. Open `Network` -> `Wireless` on your OpenWrt web interface
3. Enable your 5 Ghz network by pressing the Enable button. Try to connect to it (Don't worry about the encryption for now). If you cannot connect to it, stop here and go for troubleshooting.
4. Remove the 2.4 Ghz network by clicking the `Remove` button. (in the picture above this amounts to the `OpenWrt2` network)
5. On you 2.4Ghz *radio* / wifi device, click the `Scan` button
6. Wifi access points in your vicinity should show up.
7. Press `Join this network` on the wifi that should become your WAN
8. You should be presented with the *Joining Network* screen. It looks like this: [image]
9. Leave everything as is. Just enter the password for the wifi you're trying to join (the WAN wifi) into the `WPA passphrase` field.
10. Press `Submit`.
11. You should be presented with the *Device Conficuration Screen*. It should look like this: [image]
12. In the top (`Device Configuration`), go to `Advanced Settings`, set `Country Code` to your country. This will ensure that radio laws of your country are being followed.
13. Go down to the `Interface Configuration` section, `General Setup` tab. At `Network`, click the drop down arrow and add `lan` to the selection (so you have `lan` and `wwan` in that box). It should look something like this:
    [image: Screenshot of Interface Configuration]

- This setting is a key component: It connects LAN and WAN.

12. Click `Save`.
13. You should be back in your Wireless network configuration page. Go to the bottom and click `Save & Apply`.
14. You should now be able to connect to your internal LAN (`OpenWrt5` in my case) and access the internet from there. If not, you need to go for troubleshooting or simply try again after a reset of your device.
15. If your network works as expected, you can now set some additional settings by clicking the `Edit` button for you LAN wifi (like your security (highly recommended), maximum transmit power or MAC filter, ... )

- After you changed something, don't forget to apply the changes. Otherwise they won't have any effect.

16. And don't forget to set a root password for your OpenWrt system.

Comment: This needed one more step to work for me: I was able to connect to the 5Ghz, but it wasn't giving me an IP address. From the Wireless Overview, I had to select `Edit` on the `OpenWrt5` item (shows mode as *Master*); scroll to Interface Configuration at General Setup tab, and add `lan` at the Network dropdown. Hit `Save` button, then `Save & Apply`, then reconnected my device: boom! Now I have an IP address and Internet is working great!